# Overflow-x scroll property works on Desktop but not in mobile phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, froala

The Froala editor toolbar icons are horizontally scrollable in the desktop but not in the mobile phone.

I did a research and found that by adding -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch property, the div tag is scrollable in the mobile but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
   .fr-toolbar {
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 }
```

Here is the jsfiddle link for better understanding and reference: http://jsfiddle.net/wc5c3jhk/381/

Here is the Codepen link: https://codepen.io/Dinesh_Madhanlal/pen/Gdvxqw

Could someone throw a light on what's happening?

Comment: Could you please explain how your fiddle works? It looks like a static page.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh, Click on run and the project will run. In the editor, we have toolbar icons like bold, italic, underline, etc... I want them to be horizontally scrollable in mobile. Now, it is horizontally scrollable in the desktop. Any suggestions?

Comment: `In the editor, we have toolbar icons like bold, italic, underline, etc`, I'm unable to see these. Please create a codepen for this. As it's more flexible or StackOverflow's fiddle.

Comment: Have updated the question with the Codepen link @DhavalJardosh.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the JSFiddle as provided here -
http://jsfiddle.net/m2f8pygq/

```
.fr-toolbar {
  min-width: 300PX;
    max-width: 100%;
    /* overflow-y: hidden; */
    /* overflow-x: scroll; */
    OVERFLOW: VISIBLE;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    FLEX-WRAP: wrap;
 }
```

This will help you understand how Froala has been implemented and how the toolbar buttons are being wrapped inside a DIV when opened in Desktop or in Mobile.

In short, this is not a good option to be achieved.